# Field Update IF statement returning the wrong value while meeting conditions

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update, workflowrule

A workflow activates when a budget is input to Budget1 in an Opportunity. The workflow contains a field update.

The field update contains an IF statement that is returning the PRIORVALUE(Value1) even though the conditions provided should be met.

**The statement is as follows:**

```
IF(CONTAINS(Account.Parent.Name,"Name1") && (Value1 = null),
    4.5
    ,
IF(CONTAINS(Account.Name,"Name2") && (Value1 = null),
    3
,
PRIORVALUE(Value1)
))
```

**What I want the statement to do:**

If an opportunity parent name is Name 1 and Value1 is empty, return 4.5. Otherwise, return a value the user input into Value1.

If an opportunity account name is Name 2 and Value1 is empty, return 3. Otherwise, return a value the user input into Value1.

**What's currently happening:**

Null value being returned in Value1.

Comment: try ISBLANK(Value1) instead of Value1 = null

Comment: what is your WR criteria? Also, why do you want to use prior value?

Comment: @willard Going to test this right now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Oleksiy I'm not sure what else can be used to bring back the value that is manually input into Value1. Is there any code that retains what the user is manually changing if the first two conditions aren't met? Also, the WR Criteria is - Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it's edited.

Comment: @willard So that seemed to help the predetermined Values populate for Name1 and Name2, but now PRIORVALUE is causing either that predetermined value or a null value to populate.

Comment: are you sure the priorvalue is not actually the predetermined value or null?

Comment: @willard I see the issue - 4.5 is being populated now into that field even though it's null. Ideally if it's null it won't populate the 4.5.

Comment: I was asking what validations do you have to trigger WR? Also, in the comment from above you contradicting your requirements to populate 4.5 if the field value is null and account names is matched.

Comment: @Skobiwankanobi, I doubt that is the issue.  ISBLANK should take care of the null case as well as the blank case.  Have you tried running a debug log?